# Can I prevent DotNetNuke css from conflicting with other frameworks?

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I started to look into DotNetNuke recently as a client asked me to do so.

I noticed straight away that DNN is different from other CMS I'm familiar with in a way that it mixes its own controls with site's presentation. (Other cms like Umbraco, Wordpress, Orchard have separate interfaces for content management).

I'm building a responsive website and using Zurb foundation for it. The problem I have is that DNN's css start to mess Zurb's css. I don't want to edit neither css and the problem seems very serious. Is it addressed somehow in DNN?

Bearing in mind how popular mobile browsing has become responsive desings and hence frameworks like Zurb or Twitter bootstrap will gain more and more popularity. And it looks like DNN doesn't play nicely with them, it may become a huge no no for DNN.

The whole idea of mixing site's presentation with cms controls looks wrong to me. Is it possible to prevent them from mixing and messing with each other?

Cheers.

Comment: You're going to find that DNN is a really bad choice for this. It likes to inject it's own HTML into your markup. I moved to Umbraco for any .NET CMS tasks. You might want to plead your case to the client.

Comment: What version of DNN are you using? There have been a lot of changes in recent versions and DNN7 may resolve your problems. Having the admin interface integrated with the site is one of DNN's strengths as it make it much easier for non-technical folks to make updates to the site.

Comment: I use 6.x but literally today DNN 7.0 appeared on CodePlex, so I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Portal.css file that always gets loaded no matter what DNN skin you use. Then each DNN skin loads a skin.css file associated with the skin/theme and any other specific CSS files it needs to reference.

The issue you are probably having is that the default styles set in Portal.css are conflicting with your theme. What you may need to do is override the CSS that is causing trouble at the top of your skin file.

But yes, this does happen since DNN declares styles for modal popups, dropdowns, links etc that are used in the admin functionality and since that is inline with the actual site design they can conflict if you are using a framework like bootstrap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We created a Foundation DNN Skin specifically to solve what you're looking for - https://github.com/Ethanhackett/foundation-5-dnn-skin

It avoids the CSS conflicts and has some jQuery no conflict resolutions which need to be addressed since DNN is on jQuery v1... and Foundation is using jQuery 2...

I hope that helps.